# How to get Google Ads Tracking Template {loc_physical_ms} parameter working

Tags: google-ads-api, sem

I have Google Ads Campaigns with the following tracking template: `{lpurl}/{loc_physical_ms}`.

I have clicked on one of my live ads, but the `/{loc_physical_ms}` did not appear in the URL.

Is there a configuration I may be missing - or do I not understand the point of this ValueTrack parameter? My landing pages are already programmed to consume the ID from `{loc_physical_ms}` and generate localized content, but the parameter doesn't seem to do anything.